# Makefile: make Debug

Tags: makefile

Подскажите, как в Makefile сделать анализ входных параметров. Нужно различать Debug и Release и в зависимости от значения устанавливать в CFLAGS -g или -O2.

Comment: а что мешает сделать цель debug? и в ней выставлять. Тогда обычная сборка будет make, а отладочная - make debug.

Comment: Я так и пробую, но не получается установить флаг и запустить обычную сборку. Не подскажете, как это делается?

Comment: "Огласите весь список". Опубликуйте свой Makefile.

Comment: @alexlz, не вижу смысла публиковать свой. Его без файлов проекта не особо то потестируешь. Мне нужен самый простой пример, как реагировать на параметры и менять значения переменных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть готовый makefile, и нам нужно прикрутить к нему возможность собирать спецбилды.

В любом, нормальном Makefile есть цель `all`, которая исторически принята целью по умолчанию. (По факту, цель по умолчанию - самая первая).

Теперь пример

```
# это переменная, которая будет менять значение
# в зависимости от цели. 111 - это ее значение по умолчанию
VARR = 111

# это наша цель по умолчанию. Она просто выводит значение
all:
    echo "Test"${VARR}

# это ещё не цель. это такой способ задать переменную для цели
debug : VARR = 222

# а вот это уже настоящая цель debug. еее задача проста - просто выполнить цель debug
# и вывести текст
debug: all
    echo "Make debug version".
```

теперь можно это испытать. Единственное, что бы я сделал - так это при вызове цели debug вызвал цель clean, а то может так произойти, что файлы то не нужно перекомпилировать:) либо не забывал вызывать make clean.

[Примененный прием](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) будет работать только в gnu make.

Итого, нужно заменить мою переменную на что то более осмысленное (например `-g`) и вставить ее в команду компиляции.

Comment: Да, в gnu работает. 

В остальных не будет, т.к. в них переменные устанавливаются при первом проходе по файлу, а при втором выполняются цели. 

Соответственно VARR всегда будет 222. (точнее при такой записи не gnu make просто обругается).

Comment: а кто то против? я же написал - будет работать только в gnu make.

Comment: Написал 6 строчек вида debug: text и все заработало как хотелось.

Comment: Да сейчас это не проблема. Думаю его легко можно для любой системы найти (в крайнем случае собрать).

Я когда-то делал make для винды (кстати, с нестандартным поведением по присваиванию переменных и на первом и на втором проходах), но потом как-то набрел на gnu для винды и свой забросил.

На самом деле основная проблема со всеми такими языками, что когда постоянно на них не пишешь, то тонкости забываются (даже в своей программе).

Comment: ммм, насчет make. я подумываю, а не написать ли свою версию. Если придумаю более понятную систему сборки и найдется время, то думаю напишу.

Comment: этих систем уже хватает. cmake, qmake, imake, nmake, msbuild, ant, maven, SCons. И самое смешное, что все были разработаны, то бы заменить make:)

Comment: @mikelsv мина работодателю на случай увольнения? Мало проблем с чтением Вашего кода, так ещё make необычный...

Answer (score 2):

[@mikelsv](/users/2575/mikelsv), если вопрос только в -g, тогда можно написать в начале Makefile что-то в таком духе

```
ifndef DEBFL
DEBFL         = -O2
endif
CFLAGS        = $(DEBFL) -Dlinux  -pthread -fPIC
```

Если хотите отлаживаться

```
export DEBFL=-g
make
```

иначе

```
make clean
unset DEBFL
make
```

Я знаю, что не рекомендуется делать сборку, зависимую от environment, но для "внутреннего употребления" обычно это нормально работает.

Comment: Мне не нравится такой вариант с внешними переменными. Хотелось бы именно более стандартный с целями debug и release.

Comment: в таргете debug вам надо сетить переменную дебаг а потом уже вызывать таргет релиз + добавить логику которая сетит настройки билда в зависимости от того установлена переменная или нет (как на 1ом приведеном примере). в качестве "оптимизации" конфигурирование билд процеса можно сделать в одном файле а непосредственно таргеты для билда в другом.

Comment: можно попробовать как-то так :

    release:
        ...
    debug:
    DEBUG_MODE=true    
        make release

Comment: @mikelsv, а самый распространенный способ это просто каждый раз в редакторе начало Makefile править и не морочить (главное себе самому) голову.

Еще делают несколько Makefile-ов а в основном исполняют shell-команды, которые запускают нужные Make с параметрами. Но это тоже тот еще геморрой.